# Reading a word doc in apache poi based on pages

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is it possible to read a word document in apache poi using pagination? For eg: Can i read first 3 pages of a 5 page document and extract contents from the first 3 pages.

Comment: I don't think so. Take a look here: https://coderanch.com/t/630220/java/read-page-DOC-file

Comment: Use Word to turn it into a PDF, then read that? Word documents don't store page information...